# Intializing a mutable struct in SwiftUI

Tags: arrays, view, swiftui, initialization

I have a situation in which the user is asked to memorize an array of strings. Upon being prompted with a randomly chosen element from the array the user is asked to name the three adjacent elements. (In real life this is all about musical notes - to keep it simple I've boiled the problem down to just strings and arrays). There are two complications. First, the code should avoid showing the user the same prompt-element twice in a row. Second, at any time the user can switch between naming the elements that appear just-before the prompt-element or the elements just-after the prompt-element (musically, this corresponds to an ascending scale or a descending scale).

The `StringChooser` struct contains the array of strings and provides a function to return a randomly chosen string. It also saves the index of the randomly chosen string so that I can later use that index to find the adjacent elements.

```
struct StringChooser {
    // MARK: API
    var myStrings: [ String ]
    var lastChosenStringIndex = Int.max
    
    // MARK: Methods
    
    mutating func getRandomString() -> String {

        // pick random string that is NOT the same as previously 
        // picked element
        var randomIndex: Int
        repeat {
            randomIndex = Int.random(in: 0 ..< myStrings.count )
        } while randomIndex == lastChosenStringIndex
        

        // save the index for the picked element so that 
        // later we can find the adjacent elements
        lastChosenStringIndex = randomIndex   // supposed SAVE!

        return myStrings[ randomIndex ]
    }
}
```

The problem arises during initialization of the StringChooser struct. This is illustrated in the `ContentView` struct (below). It includes a Text subview to show the randomly chosen element from the array and a second Text subview to show the index number of the randomly chosen element. The first part works. Each time the View is shown a new string is chosen at random. The second part, however, fails. For some reason the index is never anything other than the initial value assigned to the index within the struct (which is Int.max). I don't understand why the random choice of an element works but there is no record of the corresponding index. I'd be most grateful for your thoughts on this (seeming) discrepancy.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @Binding var stringChooser: StringChooser

    @State private var chosenString = "not initialized"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Text( "Random String: \( stringChooser.getRandomString() )." )
            Spacer()
            Text("Index of chosen string: '\( stringChooser.lastChosenStringIndex )'.")
            Spacer()
            Button( "Again" )
            {
                chosenString =
                    stringChooser.getRandomString()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

[Other approaches: the same result arises if I try to use an init() to get the StringChooser instance initialized. When run in the simulator this causes a run-time warning to arise, which states that changing a State variable outside of a View can cause problems.]

Comment: Ideally, avoid mutating value-types... `StringChooser` has a state and better suited (in my opinion) to be a class. Also... `let randomIndex = myStrings.indices.randomElement()` instead of the `repeat/while` loop.

Comment: Hi New Dev!  The repeat/while thing was used to avoid showing the same prompt-string two-or-more times in a row. Sorry that I didn't make that clearer. That said, thanks for the indices.randomElement() tip. That's cool but it complicates the task when I (later) need to find the three elements that are adjacent to the prompt-element.

Comment: Oh, makes sense about the `repeat/while`... which part complicates the task? Making it a reference-type?

Comment: As I understand it the “.randomElement” function returns the actual element (not the index). Since the array isn’t necessarily sorted the question becomes how do you efficiently find the adjacent elements. It is less complicated  if the index is available.

Comment: `arr.randomElement()` returns the element of the array. `arr.indices.randomElement()` returns the element of the indices array - i.e the index. Then you can use `.index(after:)` and `.index(before:)` to find the neighboring indices

Comment: That works! Thank you very much!